# cfx_openImage and cfThread

Tags: multithreading, image-processing, coldfusion

Does cfx_openImage support multi-threading and, if so, does it make efficient use of resources?

Google was little help in this regard.  I will test this myself before moving to production, of course.  However, all of my tests multi-threading imageCR3 worked perfectly fine, yet sporadic (but serious) problems started to appear about a week into production.  So I would like to illicit feedback from anyone who may have tried implementing this in a high-volume production environment.

Specifically, I have a four core server.  Every minute a process runs that pulls a set number of images from an "awaiting processing" list.  I then cfLoop through this list processing images with imageCR3, currently in sequential order, which is slow as only one core is fully utilized.  I would like to, instead, loop with a step of four and spawn another cfThread within an inner loop to process four images in parallel:

```
<cfset stepSize = "5">
<cfloop from="1" to="#info.recordcount#" index="batchStart" step="#stepSize#">
    <cfset threadList = "">
    <cfloop query="info" startrow="#batchStart#" endrow="#Evaluate("(batchStart + stepSize) - 1")#">
        <cfset threadList = listAppend(threadList, "imageProc#info.ID#")>
        <cfthread action="run" ...>
            <CFX_OPENIMAGE CALL GOES HERE ...>
        </cfthread>
    </cfloop>
    <cfthread action="join" name="#threadList#" timeout="30000"/>
</cfloop>
```

The actual thread would call cfx_openImage multiple times on a 10+ megapixel image creating thumbnails in sizes from 1500 pixels down to 100 pixels, followed by database updates and moving the original file to an archive location.

With imageCR3 this appeared to work and ran in QA just fine.  However, in production some images would appear multiple times (presumably due to caching).  More often, image processing would simply fail with an unspecified error.  I worked with it quite a bit but could find no solution, and Efflair support ignored all of my emails.

Comment: I'm using ColdFusion 9 right now.